# Multiple applications in one IIS website with MS Release Management

Tags: devops, alm, ms-release-management, winrm

I am using the [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemname=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) extension for MS Release Management vNext template (TFS 2015 Update 2).  I can deploy a simple website so I think that my permissions and everything must be set-up properly.

My issue is that I would like to have multiple web applications hosted in a single website and deploy it automatically.

[image: Add application to website]

The **WinRM - IIS Web App Management** task does not seem to have an option for doing this.  How can I do it?

I have tried adding a **/** to the Website name however this gives me an exception:

- Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information.".

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue on [github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/issues/56) which says that you should do the following:

1. Add a Manage IIS task which creates the website
2. Add a Deploy IIS task which deploys to website\app and set the Override Parameters to `name="IIS Web Application Name", value="$(WebAppName)"` where WebAppName=website\app.

It would be a lot better if the deploy task had an option to add the website application or something.